# Make a Recyclerview Android from API but, it doesn't work

Tags: android, observable, android-recyclerview

I've been working with Recycler view Android. I try to make a Recycler view from API Response. But, the list didn't show up, my adapter was not working. When i tried to debug this program, I got `List<Produclist> list` is null.

This my JSON Response from API

```
{
  "code": 0,
  "data": [
    {
      "product_list": [
        {
          "return_level": 0,
          "image": "ee0c97c5-1752-4f1a-b713-2308eb1284d8",
          "risk_level": "Aggresive",
          "code": "P0011",
          "price": {
            "date": null,
            "value": 0
          },
          "name": "Dana Ekuitas Prima"
        },
        {
          "return_level": 0,
          "image": "ee0c97c5-1752-4f1a-b713-2308eb1284d8",
          "risk_level": "Aggresive",
          "code": "P0001",
          "price": {
            "date": "2017-01-03T11:44:52.6152Z",
            "value": 150000
          },
          "name": "Manulife Dana Saham"
        },
        {
          "return_level": 0,
          "image": "ee0c97c5-1752-4f1a-b713-2308eb1284d8",
          "risk_level": "Aggresive",
          "code": "P0008",
          "price": {
            "date": null,
            "value": 0
          },
          "name": "Trim Kapital Plus"
        },
        {
          "return_level": 0,
          "image": "ee0c97c5-1752-4f1a-b713-2308eb1284d8",
          "risk_level": "Aggresive",
          "code": "P0004",
          "price": {
            "date": "2017-01-03T11:44:52.6152Z",
            "value": 150000
          },
          "name": "Manulife Syariah Sektoral Amanah"
        }
      ],
      "type": "Reksa Dana Saham"
    }
  ],
  "info": "Product list successfully loaded"
}
```

This My setter getter

```
public class ProductListResponse {

    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    private Integer code;
    @SerializedName("info")
    @Expose
    private String info;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<CategoryType> listCategory = new ArrayList<>();

    public Integer getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(Integer code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        return info;
    }


    public void setInfo(String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public List<CategoryType> getListCategory() {
        return listCategory;
    }


    public void setListCategory(List<CategoryType> listCategory) {
        this.listCategory = listCategory;
    }


}
```

Setter getter of category type

```
    public class CategoryType {

        @SerializedName("type")
        @Expose
        private String type;

        @SerializedName("product_list")
        @Expose
        private List<ProductList> productList = new ArrayList<ProductList>();

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public List<ProductList> getProductList() {
            return productList;
        }

        public void setProductList(List<ProductList> productList) {
            this.productList = productList;
        }
}
```

Setter getter of ProductList

```
public class ProductList implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    private String code;

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("price")
    @Expose
    private Price price;

    @SerializedName("risk_level")
    @Expose
    private String riskLevel;

    @SerializedName("return_level")
    @Expose
    private Double returnLevel;

    @SerializedName("image")
    @Expose
    private String image;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getRiskLevel() {
        return riskLevel;
    }

    public void setRiskLevel(String riskLevel) {
        this.riskLevel = riskLevel;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public Price getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Price price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Double getreturnLevel() {
        return returnLevel;
    }

    public void setReturnLevel(Double returnLevel) {
        this.returnLevel = returnLevel;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
```

This my Activity

```
public class ProductActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView rvView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    public List<ProductList> list;
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.f_list_of_product);
        request(constructSignUpRequest());

        rvView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        rvView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        rvView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new ProductAdapter(context, list);
        rvView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    public BTNService.Api getApi() {
        return getBTNService().getApi();
    }

    public BTNService getBTNService() {
        return new BTNService(this);
    }

    void request(final ProductListRequest productListRequest) {
        getApi().loadproductlist(productListRequest.getCode())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Observer<ProductListResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Timber.e(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(ProductListResponse response) {
                        if (response != null) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ProductActivity.this, ProductList.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }

                    }
                });
    }

    public ProductListRequest constructSignUpRequest() {
        ProductListRequest request = new ProductListRequest();
        request.setCode(Category);
        return request;
    }

}
```

This my Adapter

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.CatalogueHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<ProductList> list;

    public ProductAdapter(Context context, List<ProductList> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public CatalogueHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_product, parent, false);
        CatalogueHolder catalogueHolder = new CatalogueHolder(itemView);
        return catalogueHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CatalogueHolder holder, int position) {
        final ProductList item = list.get(position);
        holder.itemView.setTag(item);
        holder.productName.setText(item.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list != null ? list.size() : 0;
    }

    public static class CatalogueHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @Bind(R.id.productname)
        TextView productName;
        @Bind(R.id.typeProduct)
        TextView typeProduct;
        @Bind(R.id.price)
        TextView price;
        @Bind(R.id.date)
        TextView date;

        public CatalogueHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry, if it's quite long. I have to show all my code to make it clear. I really need your help guys. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set adapter inside onComplete method:

```
void request(final ProductListRequest productListRequest) {
    getApi().loadproductlist(productListRequest.getCode())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Observer<ProductListResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                rvView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

                rvView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                adapter = new ProductAdapter(context, list);
                rvView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Timber.e(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ProductListResponse response) {
                    if (response != null) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ProductActivity.this, ProductList.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                }
            });
}
```